# vb.net NotifyIcon to show a notification without a balloon

Tags: vb.net

I have a program set up that causes a NotifyIcon to appear by the clock under certain conditions, and then disappear under other conditions, using NotifyIcon1.visible = True/False and using the Taskbar properties in Windows to set it's behavior to "Show icon and notifications". But, when it's invisible, I can't see if it's running without opening up Task Manager.

I'd like to be able to switch between having the icon show next to the clock and having it hidden with all of the other icons (the way other programs do when you select "Only show notifications"), but I can't figure out how to do that *without using a balloon tip*.

Comment: That's just not possible, only the user is in control over which icons get the preferred location.  This is the classic "what if *everybody* does this" dilemma.  And of course they do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hans. Maybe my question was unclear. I'm trying to imitate what Outlook does - they have an option to display an envelope next to the clock whenever there is unread mail, which hides once there are no unread messages.